# JSON Objects to PHP Error

Tags: php, json, object

I wrote this PHP script to echo out a whole schematic of div's with the required content.  However, when I run it, I just get a blank page.  What is wrong?

Code:

```
<?
$url = 'http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/crewapi/the_greeks_360/gtav/photo';
$json1 = utf8_encode(file_get_contents($url));

$photos = json_decode($json1, false);
foreach ($json1 as $pic)
{
    echo '<div style="opacity:0.7;width:310px;height:259px;">';
    echo '<div style="width:310px;height:174px;display:block;">';
    echo '<img src="http://prod.cloud.rockstargames.com/' . $pic->photos->Meta->ImgSrc . '" width="310" height="174" alt=""></img>';
    echo '</div><br>';
    echo '<div style="opacity:0.7;width:310px;height:52px;display:block;padding:10px;">';
    echo '<p>' . $pic->photos->Meta->location . '</p><br>';
    echo '<p><a href="http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/member/' . $pic->photos->Meta->nickname . '" target="_blank" alt="">' . $pic->photos->Meta->gamertag . '</a></p><br>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '<div style="opacity:0.9;width:310px;height:32px;display:block;padding:8px;margin-bottom:1px;">';
    echo '<a href="http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/snapmatic/photo/' . $pic->photos->Meta->Id . '" target="_blank" class="gtavicon-icon_thumbs_up"></a> ' . $pic->photos->Meta->Liked->LikeCount . '  |  ';
    echo '<a href="http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/snapmatic/photo/' . $pic->photos->Meta->Id . '" target="_blank" class="gtavicon-icon_chat"></a> ' . $pic->photos->Comments->total;
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';                  
}

?>
```

An Example of the JSON File is:

```
{
    "photos": [{
        "Meta": {
            "CreatedTimestamp": 1409242029,
            "Name": "before the destruction",
            "HardTags": ["Burton"],
            "UserTags": [],
            "Liked": {
                "Liked": false,
                "LikeCount": 7
            },
            "data": {
                "area": "BURTON",
                "street": "0",
                "scr": "1",
                "loc": {
                    "z": 40.26,
                    "x": -395.67,
                    "y": -101.2
                },
                "mode": "FREEMODE"
            },
            "location": "Burton",
            "avatar": "GTAO/gtao09.png",
            "rockstarid": "45761616",
            "platformUserId": "2535413697273494",
            "creatorMedal": "platinum",
            "plat": "XBox",
            "gamertag": "firstkiller3000",
            "crewurl": "/crew/the_greeks_360",
            "crewtag": "GRKS",
            "crewrankrev": 2,
            "crewIsPrivate": true,
            "crewIsFounderCrew": false,
            "crewColor": "#70FF03",
            "crewRankOrder": 3,
            "Id": "WsRTTpMDsUi7A8tSvNhrvQ",
            "ImgSrc": "/ugc/gta5photo/8855/WsRTTpMDsUi7A8tSvNhrvQ/0_0.jpg",
            "nickname": "killer16478"
        },
        "Comments": {
            "total": 0,
            "totalreplies": 0,
            "count": 0,
            "results": []
        }
    }, {
        "Meta": {
            "CreatedTimestamp": 1399739945,
            "Name": "Burton",
            "HardTags": ["Burton"],
            "UserTags": [],
            "Liked": {
                "Liked": false,
                "LikeCount": 6
            },
            "data": {
                "area": "BURTON",
                "street": "0",
                "scr": "1",
                "loc": {
                    "z": 54.42,
                    "x": -402.63,
                    "y": -78.48
                },
                "mode": "FREEMODE"
            },
            "location": "Burton",
            "avatar": "GTAV/gtav05.png",
            "rockstarid": "20181442",
            "platformUserId": "2533274971471462",
            "creatorMedal": "platinum",
            "plat": "XBox",
            "gamertag": "TasosNGreek",
            "crewurl": "/crew/the_greeks_360",
            "crewtag": "GRKS",
            "crewrankrev": 4,
            "crewIsPrivate": true,
            "crewIsFounderCrew": false,
            "crewColor": "#70FF03",
            "crewRankOrder": 1,
            "Id": "XPgHUpYPfEijbL59xtHOfg",
            "ImgSrc": "/ugc/gta5photo/1556/XPgHUpYPfEijbL59xtHOfg/0_0.jpg",
            "nickname": "TasosNGreek"
        },
        "Comments": {
            "total": 1,
            "totalreplies": 0,
            "count": 1,
            "results": [{
                "id": "1837034",
                "rockstarId": "24879155",
                "txt": "no comment !",
                "dt": "2014-05-14T18:56:26Z",
                "avatar": "GTAV/gtav19.png",
                "nickname": "JohnysT122",
                "replies": []
            }]
        }
    }, {
        "Meta": {
            "CreatedTimestamp": 1403048295,
            "Name": "Paleto Forest",
            "HardTags": ["PaletoForest"],
            "UserTags": [],
            "Liked": {
                "Liked": false,
                "LikeCount": 5
            },
            "data": {
                "area": "PALFOR",
                "street": "0",
                "scr": "1",
                "loc": {
                    "z": 41.81,
                    "x": -816.33,
                    "y": 5387.35
                },
                "mode": "FREEMODE"
            },
            "location": "Paleto 
Forest",
            "avatar": "MaxPayne3/MP3_46.jpg",
            "rockstarid": "35911863",
            "platformUserId": "2533274827444615",
            "creatorMedal": "platinum",
            "plat": "XBox",
            "gamertag": "banedfromb1rth",
            "crewurl": "/crew/the_greeks_360",
            "crewtag": "GRKS",
            "crewrankrev": 4,
            "crewIsPrivate": true,
            "crewIsFounderCrew": false,
            "crewColor": "#70FF03",
            "crewRankOrder": 1,
            "Id": "yf9NPUEYXU2DYFHbmddt9A",
            "ImgSrc": "/ugc/gta5photo/8221/yf9NPUEYXU2DYFHbmddt9A
/0_0.jpg",
            "nickname": "zempili"
        },
        "Comments": {
            "total": 0,
            "totalreplies": 0,
            "count": 0,
            "results": []
        }
    }, {
        "Meta": {
            "CreatedTimestamp": 1406374405,
            "Name": "Burton",
            "HardTags": ["Burton"],
            "UserTags": [],
            "Liked": {
                "Liked": false,
                "LikeCount": 4
            },
            "data": {
                "area": "BURTON",
                "street": "0",
                "scr": "1",
                "loc": {
                    "z": 54.42,
                    "x": -322.5,
                    "y": -66.55
                },
                "mode": "FREEMODE"
            },
            "location": "Burton",
            "avatar": "GTAV/gtav02.png",
            "rockstarid": "43602473",
            "platformUserId": "2533274869248155",
            "creatorMedal": "platinum",
            "plat": "XBox",
            "gamertag": "NEMESIS135",
            "crewurl": "/crew/the_greeks_360",
            "crewtag": "GRKS",
            "crewrankrev": 4,
            "crewIsPrivate": true,
            "crewIsFounderCrew": false,
            "crewColor": "#70FF03",
            "crewRankOrder": 1,
            "Id": "EVgJFeX9cUq6knR4GCAYlA",
            "ImgSrc": "/ugc/gta5photo/3388/EVgJFeX9cUq6knR4GCAYlA/0_0.jpg",
            "nickname": "manolisG13"
        },
        "Comments": {
            "total": 0,
            "totalreplies": 0,
            "count": 0,
            "results": []
        }
    }],
    "total": "419"
}
```

Comment: What "doesn't work" about this?  What does it do?  Not do?  Any errors?  Is there any more info you can give us about this problem?  What have you done to try to debug this?

Comment: P.S. Did you mean `foreach ($photos as $pic)`?

Comment: I tried to add, i do not see any results of what i suppose to see. Just blank, and yes there is a value present.

Comment: When you get "blank screen", turn on `error_reporting` and `display_errors` so you will have idea about what is going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Main problem was that you had the location of the photos key wrong.

This should work

```
$data = json_decode($json1, false);
foreach ($data->photos as $pic) {
  echo '<div style="opacity:0.7;width:310px;height:259px;">';
  echo '<div style="width:310px;height:174px;display:block;">';
  echo '<img src="http://prod.cloud.rockstargames.com/' . $pic->Meta->ImgSrc . '" width="310" height="174" alt="" />';
  echo '</div><br>';
  echo '<div style="opacity:0.7;width:310px;height:52px;display:block;padding:10px;">';
  echo '<p>' . $pic->Meta->location . '</p><br>';
  echo '<p><a href="http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/member/' . $pic->Meta->nickname . '" target="_blank" alt="">' . $pic->Meta->gamertag . '</a></p><br>';
  echo '</div>';
  echo '<div style="opacity:0.9;width:310px;height:32px;display:block;padding:8px;margin-bottom:1px;">';
  echo '<a href="http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/snapmatic/photo/' . $pic->Meta->Id . '" target="_blank" class="gtavicon-icon_thumbs_up"></a> ' . $pic->Meta->Liked->LikeCount . '  |  ';
  echo '<a href="http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/snapmatic/photo/' . $pic->Meta->Id . '" target="_blank" class="gtavicon-icon_chat"></a> ' . $pic->Comments->total;
  echo '</div>';
  echo '</div>';
}
```

I would suggest changing to use a view instead of echoing out lots of html though. Looks better and is easier to maintain.

I would probably change it to something like this (if possible in a separate view file)

```
foreach ($data->photos as $pic) { ?>
  <div style="opacity:0.7;width:310px;height:259px;">
    <div style="width:310px;height:174px;display:block;">
      <img src="http://prod.cloud.rockstargames.com/<?= $pic->Meta->ImgSrc ?>" width="310" height="174" alt="" />
    </div>
    <br>
    <div style="opacity:0.7;width:310px;height:52px;display:block;padding:10px;">
      <p><?= $pic->Meta->location ?></p><br>
      <p><a href="http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/member/<?= $pic->Meta->nickname ?>" target="_blank" alt=""><?= $pic->Meta->gamertag ?></a></p><br>
    </div>
    <div style="opacity:0.9;width:310px;height:32px;display:block;padding:8px;margin-bottom:1px;">
      <a href="http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/snapmatic/photo/<?= $pic->Meta->Id ?>" target="_blank" class="gtavicon-icon_thumbs_up"></a> <?= $pic->Meta->Liked->LikeCount ?>  |  
      <a href="http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/snapmatic/photo/<?= $pic->Meta->Id ?>" target="_blank" class="gtavicon-icon_chat"></a> <?= $pic->Comments->total ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
}
```

Next step would be to move those inline styles to the css-file where they belong :)

This is what it could look like with the styles moved into their own file

```
foreach ($data->photos as $pic) { ?>
  <div>
    <div>
      <img src="http://prod.cloud.rockstargames.com/<?= $pic->Meta->ImgSrc ?>" width="310" height="174" alt="" />
    </div>
    <div>
      <p><?= $pic->Meta->location ?></p>
      <p><a href="http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/member/<?= $pic->Meta->nickname ?>" target="_blank" alt=""><?= $pic->Meta->gamertag ?></a></p>
    </div>
    <div>
      <a href="http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/snapmatic/photo/<?= $pic->Meta->Id ?>" target="_blank" class="gtavicon-icon_thumbs_up"></a> <?= $pic->Meta->Liked->LikeCount ?>  |  
      <a href="http://socialclub.rockstargames.com/games/gtav/snapmatic/photo/<?= $pic->Meta->Id ?>" target="_blank" class="gtavicon-icon_chat"></a> <?= $pic->Comments->total ?>
    </div>
  </div>
<?php
}
```

Comment: @Prix fixed the image tags, didn't look over the html as I felt I was already venturing too far into the "code review" scene. Regarding links I think they are ok, seems like he's using icons in them.

Comment: Nope the values that you see that come out of $pic may not include the link.